# How do I make the application run in English Edition of XP while compiling it on the Chinese Edition of XP using py2exe?

Tags: python, windows, py2exe

I have compiled my Python program using py2exe in Windows XP (Chinese Edition), but it doesn't run on Windows XP (English Edition). When I run it in the English Edition of Windows XP, the window says:

> This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix the problem.

How do I make the application run in English Edition of XP while compiling it on the Chinese Edition of XP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is not with the language that you create your .exe.
review this thread [Application has failed to start ... application configuration is incorrect - VC++ 2005 Runtime Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265481/application-has-failed-to-start-application-configuration-is-incorrect-vc).
You have to include dlls of VC++ runtime as follow:

```
Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest
msvcm90.dll
msvcp90.dll
msvcr71.dll
msvcr90.dll
```

Put it on into your dist folder. And test exucute your app in windows XP in English language.

Comment: where shall i download the dlls? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Review this link [link](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step521), maybe you have installed on it directory, follow this path C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_none_e163563597edeada\

By the other hand lookin for google vc++ runtime ,look this [link1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/aa570309) and [link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Hope it helps you.